# ngx-permissions - no hard coded permission names in html

Tags: angular

I am using [ngx-permissions](https://github.com/AlexKhymenko/ngx-permissions/wiki) in my Angular 6 application.  I have many permissions that will be used throughout the application and so I would like to have a constants file with all the permission names - for example:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Permission {
  public static CanViewX = 'CanViewX';
  public static CanEditX = 'CanEditX';
  public static CanAdministerX = 'CanAdministerX';
}
```

I can reference this Permission class when checking the permissions in typescript:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxPermissionsService } from 'ngx-permissions';
import { Permission } from '../data/permission';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Service {

  constructor(private permissionsService: NgxPermissionsService) { }

  checkPermission() {
      this.permissionsService.hasPermission(Permission.CanViewX);
  }
}
```

However I'm struggling to use my Permission class when checking permissions in html.  The second `<p>` is never shown despite my user definitely having that permission. Hard coding the name of the permission will work, but I would like to use my class as I can see there will be typos and mistakes if developers have to remember the permission names.

```
<p *ngxPermissionsOnly="['CanViewX']">This will work</p>
<p *ngxPermissionsOnly="[Permission.CanViewX]">Viewers should be able to see this, but can't</p>
```

Is there a way to avoid hard coding my permission names in html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I didn't want to hardcode the permission names in html, so I created a property in the .ts file, and bound to it in html.